# Cannot resize update-manager window

Tags: update-manager, resize

On 18.04 the `update-manager` window shows more boiler plate than actual content (see below) and I cannot resize it.

Is it possible to change some setting somewhere to be able to resize the window?

[image]

Comment: If you have *dconf-editor* installed, open it to */apps/update-manager* and play with the height and width settings. Note that the default height value is `400` whereas the width value seems to be `1`. So the height vaule seems to refer to pixels but the width doesn't.

Comment: And you'll have to wait till the next round of updates to see the effect :)

Comment: Note to self: it seems to be necessary to **not** have the update-manager open while changing the values. Otherwise it probably rewrites the values when closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wmctrl. E.g. to move the update-manager window to x=10, y=10 with width=400, height=400:

```
wmctrl -r :SELECT: -e '0,10,10,400,400'
```

The option -r :SELECT: means that you can select the window you want to resize/move after having entered the command.